# Is there a "MacGyver" like chalenge theme park / adventure park / place?

Tags: where-on-earth, amusement-parks

As a kid I use to love the TV series "[MacGyver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGyver)". Yesterday, speaking to a friend we started wondering if there was something like a theme park or similar like the TV series. Basically a place with several different sets. In each set you would face a challenge that you would have to solve with whatever you had at hand in that set.

Is there something like this? if yes, where?

My geographical preference is Europe, but it can be anywhere else.

P.s. - the park doesn't need to be related in terms of branding or endorsement  with the TV series. It just needs to present similar challenges.

[image: Richard Dean Anderson em 1985]

Comment: Sounds like you want a *murder mystery weekend* kind of thing?

Comment: @Liam your sugestion sounds intersting but I would classify that more as "Hercule Poirot" thing than MacGuyver. In any case if you know something like that go ahead and post it as an answer.

Comment: Did you watch the latest [webisode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMV4R1FWccA)?

Comment: @MeNoTalk :) I was glad to see him again.. but the webisode was a bit disappointing at the same time.

Comment: @nsn yes true, but its better than nothing, a glimpse of the past...

Answer (score 12):

It's not a theme park but I recently discovered something that relates with my question. There is a new trend called "escape rooms". These are a physical adventure game where you have to solve a set of puzzles and escape from a room / scenario. A lot like MacGyver did.

Basically you are put in a room, with a theme, from where you have to escape. Themes can vary a lot, both in subject and dificulty. You usually pick from the available ones and there can be scenarios like the mad scientist lab, a II world war jail or an abandoned house from a drug cartel. Imagination is the limit. Optionally there can be actors to make the set more engaging.

This is something that has been developing since 2010 and you can find them in most major cities. If you want to find out just google the city name + "escape room" to find some results.

More details in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_room

[image: Escaper room]

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe that there are any theme parks that have what you are describing, but in the uk there is a company offering spy / espionage interactive experiences

http://www.spy-games-experiences.com

This orbitz blog also details some international locations with an espionage flavour.

http://www.orbitz.com/blog/2013/09/vacation-undercover/